# Inserting Lookup columns into Data View Web part displays as XML

Tags: data-view-web-part, 2010

I am trying to configure a Data View web part in SP Designer 2010. 
I am connecting it to a list called Data Returns.

Data Returns includes a mixture of Fields, some text, some choice, some lookup.

Whenever I insert a lookup field into the DVWP the data displays as raw html like this:

```
<a onclick="OpenPopUpPage('http://****/departments/ITG/IRP/DPAR/_layouts/listform.aspx?PageType=4&ListId={A655B962-2383-44F4-8FFA-BB2BD72D8***}&ID=10&RootFolder=*', RefreshPage); return false;" href="http://****/departments/ITG/IRP/DPAR/_layouts/listform.aspx?PageType=4&ListId={A655B962-2383-44F4-8FFA-BB2BD72D****}&ID=10&RootFolder=*">P309 - TOM1.</a>
```

All that should be displayed is "P309 - TOM1". 
Is this a known issue with Lookups and DVWP? 
Is their an easy way of coverting this to the actual data value?

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to do some substring functions to get the data.  In this case, you'd do something like this, you might need to encode the special characters like " < >:

```
<xsl:value-of select="substring-after(substring-before(@YourColumn, '</a>'), 'RootFolder=*">')" />
```

This is also the case with fields like Person/group fields if you want plain text values and not hyperlinks.  You can check out some of the XSLT telpates thaat are posted on [spxslt.codeplex.com](http://spxslt.codeplex.com).  This might make a good addition to the templates.

Comment: Thanks PirateEric. I found another solution by selecting the cell and clicking "format as label". However, if I was to implement your suggestion, would I need to switch to code view to enter the xsl above?

Comment: Yep, that would be for the code view.  You might have to tinker with it slightly, it's purely untested code.  Typically, you have to escape the special characters.

Comment: @Stephen - I was excited to find such a simple solution, but when I format as label, I'm still getting a hyperlink. would you be willing to share the code of your label-formatted field so I can compare with mine? (assuming you have still have access to it..)

Comment: @PirateEric - I found a solution even _I_ could understand on your linked codeplex resource via the [StripHTML template](https://spxslt.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=StripHTML). Thanks much for sharing!

Answer (score 0):

To render field without escaping you can use following attribute:

```
<xsl:value-of disable-output-escaping="yes" select="@MultiLookupTest_x003a_TestField"/>
```

From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms256181%28v=vs.120%29.aspx):

> disable-output-escaping
>
> Default is "no". If the value is "yes", a text node generated by instantiating the  element will be output without any escaping.
>
> Consider disable-output-escaping="yes" an advanced feature, to be used only when the potential dangers are understood.