# SP2010: How to display a lookup column in a .aspx displayform

Tags: sharepoint-designer, lookup-column, xpath

- I have the two Lists Articles(A) and Serial Inspections(S).
- The Article-List has columns: Article-#, Name, DescriptionDE, DescriptionEN, somemore...
- The Serial Inspections: Inspection-#, Inspector, Values and a lookup column which refers to the Article-#.
- In Addition to that in SP2010 you can choose some more Columns which are Displayed in the Serial Inspections list which are then Named like: Article-#:Name.
- Now i took the Sharepoint Designer2010 and made myself a Printable Form of a single listitem in Serial Inspections. I basically took the displayform.aspx and made changes. Accessing it by link /printform.aspx?ID=1234 to show the entry with ID 1234.
- I can select the Lookup Column Article-# itself. Now its important for me to show the additional lookup column Article-#:Name but i cant choose it from the x-path list.

---

> Good approach:
>   I got the HiddenID of the Lookup Column Artikel-#: "Artikel_x002d_*x0023*" and the Additional Lookup Column Artikel-#:Name 's ID is: "Artikel_x002d_*x0023*_x003a_Arti"
>   So i tried: `<xsl:value-of select="@Artikel_x002d__x0023__x003a_Arti" />`

Sadly that doesnt show anything... but the Artikel-# Column does work

Answer (score 1):

You can select it by the column's hidden name. When you go to "List Settings" of Inspection list, you will find this column Article-#:Name. Click on this and in the url, you will get the hidden name of the column.
Then in your display form you can select the column as:

`<xsl:value-of select="@{HiddenNameOfTheColumn}" />`

Comment: Clicked on it and URL is: ?View={bcf8e73b-99ad-4817-bc19-98ad6547043d}&SortField=Artikel_x002d__x0023__x003a_Arti&SortDir=Asc  Now should i take the bcf8e... or Artikel_x002d... number?

Comment: in the url copy the value of "Field" parameter. It will be like "Field=TilteLookup%5Fx003a%5FTest1". In this replace "%5F" by "_"; so the hidden name will be "TilteLookup_x003a_Test1"

Comment: You have to go to "Inspections" list settings; there in the column list click on your column name. Then you will get this url.

Comment: Okay the Lookup Column Artikel-# itself is: Artikel%5Fx002d%5F%5Fx0023%5F BUT: I need the Additional lookups (Artikel-#:Name which are Selectable on that page you mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're looking for sth. like this (called from a Serial Inspections context):

```
<xsl:value-of select="Article[Article_x002d_x0023=@Article_x002d_x0023]/@Name" />
```

i.e. go to the Article list and get all (it's just one) entries with Article-# equal to the reference Article-# in your current Serial Inspections item and return the Name attribute.

Oh and try to avoid all characters that are not in [a-zA-Z0-9_] if you want to avoid these difficult to read hex numbers in your code. :-)

Comment: That sounds exactly what i want! But how to contact my Article-list. In my Case it must be sth like this: - <xsl:value of select="ArtikelStammdatenKopie[Artikel_x002d__x0023_=@Artikel_x002d__x0023_]/@Artikel_x002d_Bezeichnung" /> But that wont work... I think i dont use the correct list anme of the Article-list.

Comment: What you tried looks good to me (apart from the dash between 'value' and 'of' you missed), but it depends on the context it's in. The XPath SharePoint list entries use have a structure below them that's /Rows/Row/<attribute> (see Data Source Details panel in SP Designer), i.e. 
if you're coming from another context (SerialInspections), you might need sth. like

    <xsl:value-of select="/dsQueryResponse/ArtikelStammdatenKopie/Rows/Row[Artikel_x002d__x0023_=@Artikel_x002d__x0023_]/@Arti‌​kel_x002d_Bezeichnung" />

Comment: Do i have add to my Data Source the ArtikelStammdatenKopie Data Source? I think i can't acces the data of the other list.

Comment: I added the other Data Source then my current approach is: <xsl:value-of select="../../../Artikel-Stammdaten/Rows/Row[../../../Artikel-Stammdaten/Rows/Row/@Artikel_x002d__x0023_=@Artikel_x002d__x0023_]/@Artikel_x002d_Bezeichnung" /> But it just returns the first value of Bezeichnung...

Comment: I could make it if i just had the ID of that Lookup Item im searching.. But the Value for Artikle in the Serial Inspections list is "<a onclick=........>ARTICLENO" and NOT just ARTICLENO. I displayed the value by formatting the Value as a Label so i just get the ARTICLENO. But i cant lookup that way -.- ...

Comment: No... Its just to slow anyhow! Page needs 1 minute to load every time since i added the other data source. Doesnt work that way. I just made a column in list A and stored the Bezeichnung with a WF.

Comment: > But the Value for Artikle in the Serial Inspections list is "<a onclick=........>ARTICLENO" and NOT just ARTICLENO.


Looks like a copy & paste error in the page code somewhere.