# Lookup Column Values With and Without ID;# in SPD with DVWPs

Tags: data-view-web-part, lookup-column

I see this difference when I'm working with lists in Data View Web Parts and manipulating the values in XSL. Why do some Lookup column values look like '1;#text' and others just have the text? I've never been able to figure that out.

It may have something to do with the Site Definition, but I'm just guessing. I've seen this difference in both SharePoint 2007 and 2010.

Right now I'm working in 2007, with lookups to Title columns in other lists. In this case, I don't have the ID;#. It seems to be consistent within installations.

Generally speaking, I would *always* prefer to see the ID;#, as I can then do much more reliable matching in my AggregateDataSources than if I have to use the text values.

Comment: I've never seen one without the delimiter. When are you seeing these? Or where? Do you have examples?

Comment: I added some clarification above.

Comment: If you access the same LookUp column from the server object model does it return the same value?

Comment: I've seen http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/13201/inserting-lookup-columns-into-data-view-web-part-displays-as-xml and http://jeevansd.blogspot.com/2012/03/removing-link-from-lookup-column-in.html about DVWP returning a link to the column.

Comment: Can you do a "GetList" call on the list that is affected and a list that isn't? Maybe comparing the fields, something may show up in there.

Comment: In U2U CAML builder, I see the ID;# for the lookup columns. It's just in the DVWP that I don't.

Comment: @MarcDAnderson in SPD, what do you see when you display the datasource itself (not the DVWP)? I have noticed that datasources have two representations of lookup columns, but I always pick the one with ID;#

Comment: That's true in 2010, right? But I'm looking at 2007 at the moment. However, I think that I've seen this in both versions.

Answer (score 4):

Use this:

`<xsl:value-of select="substring-after(@Manufacturer.,'#')"/>`

instead of

`<xsl:value-of select="Manufacturer."/>`

for the look up column

Answer (score 1):

From what I've read about LookUp columns and DVWP, in DVWP (and only in DVWP) LookUp columns get returned as a link to the column and the actual value (rather than the delimited value).

The data stored in the `SPListItem` still has the delimited value internally. It is not however surfaced in the DVWP.

It's just an illusion that the data is not stored as such.

See:

[Inserting Lookup columns into Data View Web part displays as XML](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/13201/inserting-lookup-columns-into-data-view-web-part-displays-as-xml)

http://codeforfuture.com/2011/03/15/how-to-remove-link-for-sharepoint-lookup-column-from-a-dataview-webpart-using-xslt/

http://jeevansd.blogspot.com/2012/03/removing-link-from-lookup-column-in.html

Comment: I added yet more info above. I'd really like to *always* see the ID;#.

Comment: But that's not how the DVWP works. The data is stored internally like you want it, but the DVWP renders it like you're seeing it. It's a behavior of the DVWP not the SPListItem.

Comment: Your question is "Why is it like this?" This is the answer.

Comment: I think you're answering a different question than I'm asking. I'm writing my own XSL in the DVWP, not just clicking on buttons in the ribbon. In some environments I see the ID;# in lookup column values and in others I don't. I'm wondering why there;s a difference.